# Advice for optimizing my search for available times for user(s) given list of their events. (Currently using for loop inside while loop)

Tags: apex, loop, performance

I am finding the next 5 available time slots for a user or group of users based on events they have on their calendar.

Currently, I have a while loop that will start at the selected time, then loop through all events within the time frame, and if no events overlap, it will be added to my available times. If an event does overlap with the selected time, the selected time moves to the end of the event, the event loop breaks, and we start at the top of the while loop, which restarts the for loop of events to search through all the events again to see if anything overlaps with the new selected time.

Once 5 times have been found (or it looked a month ahead and didn't find anything), the while loop breaks and the times that were found are returned.

I am just wondering if anyone might have a more optimized way of doing this that doesn't involve a for loop inside a while loop (where the while loop has no clear ending).

**My description of what is happening is basically the pseudo code for what I have going on. I am really just looking for a way to optimize this kind of behavior (finding available times for user(s) given a list of their events) in an explanation or pseudo code kind of style.

Perhaps doing this just requires a while loop and a for loop of events inside it like I have...

Comment: There's probably some topic in the Computer Science sphere that relates to this, but I don't know about it off the top of my head (i.e. I don't think there's an easy and obvious better solution). It's good to keep in mind that premature optimization is bad. What performance measurements have you taken so far? Are you running into governor limits? What are the most extreme cases you want to handle? If you have something that already works, you really should be able to answer all of those questions _before_ trying to optimize.

Comment: My solution works and doesn't hit governor limits. It is just repeatedly restarting the for loop of events for each new time slot I am looking at seems not great, but can't really think of a better way :(. I could remove events that start and end before my current time slot, but that doesn't seem like it would do a ton. I put a month look out cap on it to avoid governor limit issues. Otherwise it could search forever for really busy users/large groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can help "automate" this by overriding hashCode and equals on a custom class, but this is not much more efficient than it would be to do this while loop manually; in fact, if you have a large number of items, it can result in a significant performance penalty. Here's what that generally looks like:

```
public class DateRange {
  DateTime begins, ends;
  public DateRange(DateTime b, DateTime e) {
    begins = b;
    ends = e;
  }
  public Integer hashCode() {
    return 1;
  }
  public Boolean equals(Object o) {
    DateRange r = (DateRange)o;
    return begins < r.ends && ends > r.begins;
  }
}
```

You use this class using a Map or Set. Be aware that adding an item where contains returns true will result in undefined (bad) behavior. Always check if it's in range first.

## Usage

```
Set<DateRange> ranges = new Set<DateRange>();
for(... currentRange ...) {
  if(!ranges.contains(currentRange)) {
    ranges.add(currentRange);
  } else {
    // There's an overlap if you get here. Handle it.
  }
}
for(... newRange ...) {
  if(!ranges.contains(newRange)) {
    // Available slot here
    ranges.add(newRange);
  }
}
```

As you can see, it *looks* prettier, but may or may not result in actual performance gains. The only main benefit to this is that since you're marshalling into the Apex Code library, you get to (temporarily) circumvent most governor limit checks, resulting in a very minor boost in performance.